I'm building an ER Model, I Want to make a relaction of tables to workers, but only if they are waiters (I also have a positions table)
I have 3 tables, a workers table (atributes are: residence,date,phoneN,name), the positions (atributes are: name,wage,description) for that workers, and the tables (atributes are:number), I want to make a relation of the workers (that are waiters) to tle Tables, and a relaction of the positions to the workers.
enter image description here
I tried the aproach of the image above, but doesn't guarantee that only the workers that are waiters can be rellated to a table.

You will have to handle this manually in code, there are no such possibilities in SQL
